# What is the correct way of handling exceptions in Spring Batch listeners?

Tags: java, spring, listener, spring-batch

When using an `ItemWriteListener` (or similar) from Spring Batch, what is the correct way to handle checked exceptions thrown be delegates of the listener?

For example:

```
public class MyClass implements ItemWriteListener<MyDTO> {
    // fields and constructor omitted

    @Override
    public void beforeWrite(List<MyDTO> items) {
        try {
            repository.loadAll(); // <-- Throws some checked exception
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // What to do here?
        }
    }
    // other methods omitted
}
```

How should I handle that exception? Here are a few ideas:

1. Rethrow in a `RuntimeException`
2. Log the exception and let the step fail down the line where it depends on the action of this listener
3. Set some indicator on the `MyDTO` items to indicate a failure

Of course, I can't throw the checked exception, because it is not declared on the `ItemWriteListener` interface.

Comment: one important aspect: do you want the transaction (and processed chunk) to Roll-Back? beforeWrite() runs inside the transaction for the whole chunk, so a "rethrow" will cause a roll-back (see javadoc http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemWriteListener.html )

Comment: @MichaelPralow that is what I need, because an exception here indicates an invalid state of the process.

Answer (score 5):

Throw a runtime exception, if the reader/writer depends on this action. This way, you can be sure that SpringBatch handles the transaction and the updates of the SpringBatch db-tables correctly.